# How to prevent single quotes turning my parameter into a string when using a workspace runner?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, fme-form, query

I have run the below query successfully on a spatial database in a standalone workspace:

```
st_intersects(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('$(poly)'), 27700), geom)
```

The poly parameter brings in wkt dynamically.

When I pass the paramater through a master workspace and run the query in the child workspace it treats '$poly' as a string rather than a parameter. If I remove the single quotes the WKT comes through as expected, however the single quotes are part of the spatial query so the SQL fails.

Has anyone got any advice on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having encountered a similar problem with passing parameters through to child workspaces I have stumbled upon the underlying issue and answer here. The string was not being split by single quotes but was in fact split on the commas inside the WKT.

To prevent parameters being split at commas make sure the parameter type is set to Text (Multiline)

[image]

The draw back to this change is that alot more characters are used e.g. 137665494, 142465377 becomes '137665494'<'comma>'<'space>'142465377'. This can create issues with the character limits for parameters in FME.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you've posted this on the [**FME Knowledge Centre**](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/36933/how-to-prevent-single-quotes-turning-my-parameter.html).  If none of those solutions work for you, have you tried creating a **[Scripted Python Parameter](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/!Transformer_Parameters/scripted_python_tcl.htm)**?

[image]

Try wrapping your expression in double quotes for the value.  Then you can pass that parameter into your master workspace.  If that doesn't work, try escaping the single quotes as so:

```
\'
```

So your expression might look like:

```
"st_intersects(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext(\'$(poly)\'), 27700), geom)"
```

[image]

Comment: I've upvoted this as it offers an alternative method but i haven't accepted it as correct as it, along with most FME solutions, diverts away the issue rather than resolving it. I resorted to running the query in the parent workspace. Hopefully the answer is still out there....